# Integration of my widget with my application

Tags: android, android-widget

I have made a widget that is working fine on its part and also i have made and app for that is working well too in its part.
Now i want to integrate this widget into my application such that both are under same package.

how can i do this ??
do i have to make changes in manifest file.
I have done R&D but all links are for developing the widget from the start..none is on integration.

i have seen alot but found nothing helpful. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: copy all code from one package to 2nd one and merge AndroidManifest.xml ...

Comment: @selvin..ok let me do like this

Comment: answer your own question and accept it so this question doesn't appear unanswered/unresolved :)

Comment: I am also same problem please explain in details........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work for me by copying all my widget files to the project to which i want to integrate into.
Now when i install the application in the device, its widget also gets installed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an apologist of [Copy-and-paste programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming), so after a bit research we found a way to integrate a widget into several different projects.

- Turn the Widget project into a Library project : `properties ->
  Android ->` and tick `Is Library`
- Go to the original project and import the Widget project :
  `properties -> Android -> Add`
- In the original project's Manifest, add the text between the
  `<receiver>(...)</receiver>`, including `<intent-filter />` and
  `<meta-data/>`, into the `<application>(...)</application>`

And presto, App + Widget integration with no Copy-Paste programming!