# How can I Integrate my Widget Application into my another Application

Tags: android

Hi guy's Please See the question asked on this link[ [Integration of my widget with my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001296/integration-of-my-widget-with-my-application) ][1]

[1]: 
My problem is exactly same as the question asked on this link. 
Very first I have tried this Ans=>

1] 
    i) Turn the Widget project into a Library project : properties -> Android -> and tick Is Library
    ii) Go to the original project and import the Widget project : properties -> Android -> Add
    iii)In the original project's Manifest, add the text between the  (...) , including  and , into the  (...) 
 But this didn't work for me.. Then I tried second ans i.e.---

2] Copy all code from one package to 2nd one and merge AndroidManifest.xml ...

But in this case My both application i.e. widget App and Another app has MainActivity.. So there is ambiguity between them.. ! Please help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved my problem, what I did is--

I have copied all Activities, Classes and Services form my widget app to my another app. 
After that I have merged the both Manifest files (One from widget app. and one from my another app) into my another app, so that it is a single Manifest file. And the main problem was my widget app and another app both had the activity with same name i.e. MainActivity, so to resolve this problem I've just renamed MainActivity from my widget app to StartActivity, and problem got solved, now application is running fine.!